# Opposite of Push(); (splice explanation)

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

Say I have a array

```
var arrayName = [];
```

with three items

```
arrayName = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello'];
```

how do I delete the item 'hey' from the array?

Comment: Java and javascript are two different languages.

Comment: arrayName.splice(1,1); // remove from pos#1, 1 element

Answer (score 0):

```
var hey = arrayName.splice(1,1);
```

EDIT: If you would prefer to get the index of a particular value, you can use:

```
arrayName.indexOf("hey");
```

Comment: deleting just changes the value, it doesn't remove the array item or affect the .length unless you do the last one...

Comment: @dandavis - Derp! You're right. I keep assuming the delete keyword affects objects and arrays the same way. Edited.